# Unable to find `ReturnCode` from ffmpeg in Flutter

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg

Here is a snippet that does not compile due to the `Unable to find` ReturnCode`` error message.

What's missing?

```dart
import 'package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter/ffmpeg_kit.dart';

class Video {

  /// Executes the command
  void execute(String command) async {
    FFmpegKit.execute(command).then((session) async {
      final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();

      if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {
        // SUCCESS

      } else if (ReturnCode.isCancel(returnCode)) {
        // CANCEL

      } else {
        // ERROR

      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ReturnCode class](https://pub.dev/documentation/ffmpeg_kit_flutter/latest/return_code/ReturnCode-class.html) is defined in `return_code` library. You should import it before use:

```
import 'package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter/return_code.dart';
```